# how to insert large data in ms access database in java?

Tags: java, ms-access

Here is my code:

```
{
     try
 {
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD SHAHAB\\real estate.accdb");
    String username=shah.getText();
    String password=String.valueOf(jd.getPassword());
    String address=haf.getText();
    String mobile=mensa.getText();
    String email=text.getText();
    String role= misa.getText();
    String country=unity.getText();
    String city=cety.getText();
    String company=milan.getText();
    PreparedStatement pst;
    pst=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO simba (Username,Password,Address,Mobile No,Email Address,Role,Country,City,Company)"+"values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    pst.setString(1,username);
    pst.setString(2,password);
    pst.setString(3,address);
    pst.setString(4,mobile);
    pst.setString(5,email);
    pst.setString(6,role);
    pst.setString(7,country);
    pst.setString(8,city);
    pst.setString(9,company);
    int i=pst.executeUpdate();
    if(i>0)
 {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"data is saved");
 }
    else
 {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"data is not saved");
 }
 }

     catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
}
 }

                                         });
```

I am trying to insert data in a single row having eight columns in ms access database,[when i run the progrom i got the following messsage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W67a.png).
This my ms access table[MY Ms access table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDUFH.png) 
What am i doing wrong

Comment: Looks like your table has no field `mobile`

Comment: @Jens i have created mobile field in my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some brackets:

```
pst=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO simba (Username,[Password],Address,[Mobile No],[Email Address],Company)"+"values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: Now, my java app is  inserting data in database properly after putting some brackets